# Python + Mysql TypeError

Tags: python, mysql

im trying to insert some rows into my mysql database, but i get this error:

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

My code is:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO galgos (`hora`,`circuito`,`metros`,`puesto`,`nombre`,`entrenador`,`edad`,`peso`,`curva`,`tiempo`) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')""", (hora[0],hora[1],saludos[:3],nombre,entrenador,edad,peso,curva,tiempo))
```

Comment: You need to pass in 10 arguments. Currently passing *9*.  `saludos[:3]` is a list

Answer (score 0):

You set to pass 10 arguments with `%s`, however you passed only 9. 
Seems like `metros` is missing from the arguments.